# three.js How to put scene into table

Tags: html, three.js

How is it possible to put three.js scene into html table? To draw cube in first column. I tried this but it did not work:

```
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
<table style="position:relative; width:100%; border-style: dotted;">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <script src="three.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1, 0.1, 1000);

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(500, 500);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(0.5,0.5,0.5);
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            scene.add(cube);

            camera.position.z = 5;
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            document.write('Cube');
        </script>
    </td>
    <td>Column2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column1</td>
    <td>Column2</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Thanks,
Ievgeniia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="some_id"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```js
var container = document.getElementById( 'some_id' );
var R = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
container.appendChild( R.domElement );
```

So you create element, locate it using getElementById function and assign it as renderer's draw-to html element (domElement). Hope this helps.

- - - 

With line:

```
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

You create renderer's draw-to element (canvas) directly to < body > which causes "full-screen" drawing.